# Reflection on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some confusion reflection on complex plane. My question is "Prove that **W** ∈ C is the reflection of **Z** ∈ C in the line $$ \bar bz + b\bar z + c= 0 $$ if and only if $$ \bar bZ + b\bar W  + c= 0 $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** We have $c\in\Bbb R$ and we can assume $\bar bb=1$, as scaling the equations keep them valid. 
You can express $W$ by $Z$ from the equation, and should prove e.g. that $W-Z$ orthogonal to the line, i.e. $=rb$ with a real $r$, and that the midpoint $\frac{Z+W}2$ is on the line.